# how to make it using https for a website using google cloud launcher?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google cloud launcher to set up a Drupal instance. It went quite well. But the problem is that I can only access the drupal site by http, which is http://146.148.100.235. Hope someone can advise me on how to set up a secure https visiting over this?

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to first buy a ssl certificate. Then you need to configure your web server so it listens on https port 443. After that you need to open the https port for your google compute instance.